# Select Query in Firebase Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase realtime database...
I need to select a password where user ='Admin'
I am new to fire base ...

```
   {"users":[{
        "user": "Admin",
        "password":"abcd"
    },
    {
        "user": "emp",
        "password":"json"
    },
    {
        "user": "Test Name",
        "password":"12345"
    }

    ]}
```

[Android Platform]

```
 DatabaseReference databaseUesrs = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
```

Comment: I'd suggest starting with the documentation for performing queries. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
DatabaseReference databaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
databaseUsers.orderByChild("user").equalTo("Admin").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
   String password = ds.child("password").getValue(String.class);
    }
 }
   @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
   throw databaseError.toException();
  }
 });
```

Using `orderByChild().equalTo()`  you can create a `where` query that will retrieve data  based on the result of this query.

Comment: String password returning null...  when i toasted  dataSnapshot .. i got "DataSnapshot {key = users,value={0={password=abcd,user=Admin}} }"